# $\min\{f(x,y),g(x,y)\}$ is also quasiconcave for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ quasiconcave functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebraic-topology, self-learning

> Assume that $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are quasiconcave functions, then $\min\{f(x,y),g(x,y)\}$ is also quasiconcave.

What I did:

Assume that $\{(u,v), (z,t)\}$ are domain of $f$ and $g$ for $0<\theta<1$

$f$ is quasiconcave then $\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=f(\theta (u,v)+(1-\theta)(z,t))\\&=f(\theta u+(1-\theta)z, \theta v+(1-\theta)t)\\&>\min( f(u,v), f(z,t) )\\&=f(z,t)\end{aligned}$

$g$ is quasiconcave then $\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=g(\theta (u,v)+(1-\theta)(z,t))\\&=g(\theta u+(1-\theta)z, \theta v+(1-\theta)t)\\&>\min( g(u,v), g(z,t) )\\&=g(z,t)\end{aligned}$

I assume that $m(x,y)=\min(f(x,y), g(x,y))$

I want to show that $\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=m(\theta (u,v)+(1-\theta)(z,t))\\&=m(\theta u+(1-\theta)z, \theta v+(1-\theta)t)\\&>\min( m(u,v), m(z,t) )\end{aligned}$

$$\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=m(\theta (u,v)+(1-\theta)(z,t))\\&=m(\theta u+(1-\theta)z, \theta v+(1-\theta)t)\\&=\min(f(\theta u+(1-\theta)z, \theta v+(1-\theta)t), g(\theta u+(1-\theta)z, \theta v+(1-\theta)t))\\&=\end{aligned}$$

And then, how can I proceed this proof?

Any helps will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything with $$\min\{f(x,y),g(x,y)\}=\frac{f(x,y)+g(x,y)-|f(x,y)-g(x,y)|}2$$?

Comment: No. How can I do this proof by using your suggestion? I cannot imagine it @Invisible

Comment: You should edit your question to include the definition of "quasiconcave".

Comment: In fact, all I did is the definition of quasiconcavity. @PaulFrost

Comment: @1190 This may be so, but I think that everybody should precisely understand what "quasiconcave" means. You do not give a definitiion, therefore you expect that it is commonly known (which I doubt) or that the reader makes research to find the definition. Yes, the interpretation of "quasiconcave" may be implicit in  your question (though probably only recognisable to readers knowing the definition), but questions should be **self-contained**.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\min\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{c,d\}\}=\min\{\min\{a,c\},\min\{b,d\}\}$$

Comment: I don’t understand how I can use this hint? So sorry.

Comment: @1190 Let $a=f(u,v)$, $b=f(z,t)$, $c=g(u,v)$ and $d=g(z,t)$.